# Can you set initial buffer for Clappr Player?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, clappr

We are using Clappr Player to live stream HLS.

We are trying to make the video start playing quicker.

Anyone know if there is a way to set the initial buffer size of Clappr Player?

I want to set it lower to seep up the video starting...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Clappr uses `hls.js`. You should be able to pass a `hlsjsConfig` object in the player's configuration. You can find the fine-tuning options [here](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/doc/API.md#fine-tuning).

That being said you probably need to tweak the HLS encoding too.